# How to reference .less files in _Layout

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5, less

I am using Bootstrap 3 Datepicker to use the DateTimePicker and I have downloaded the Nuget Package for this.

Now it is downloaded but I am unable to reference the files in my `_Layout` Shared view.  I try to just drag and drop the file in there and then change the syntax to the razor style `@Styles.Render("~/xxx/xxx")`but everytime I try to drop it, nothing happens.

Is there something that I am missing. How do I reference these?

Answer (score 0):

In my `_Layout`s for MVC, we just do it like this:

```
<link href="~/Xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I don't believe it is necessary to use Razor syntax just to link a style sheet, but maybe if you want to render a bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Okay in Nuget there is a `.CSS` version of Bootstrap v3 for the datetimepicker.  once I downloaded that I was able to reference them in my `_Layout` view.